# Using XIRR with Calculated Dates in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to find the Internal Rate of Return of the following data:

[image: table of data]

I've tried a whole bunch of formulas in R4C2 entered both as standard formulas or as array formulas, and nothing seems to work. Do I have to put the dates in cells on the spreadsheet, or is it possible to put the dates in the formula as a calculation. Here's an example of some of the things I've tried:

```
=XIRR(R[-3]C:R[-2]C,   {Today();Today()+30*R[-1]C})

=XIRR({R[-3]C;R[-2]C}, {Today();Today()+30*R[-1]C})
```

Again, I've tried entering these with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key
and with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
It always just tells me there's a problem with the formula. Can it be done with a formula, or do I have to put the calculated dates into an adjacent range of cells?

Comment: In Excel, array constants can contain only text, numbers, Booleans and error values.  They cannot contain formulas.  So, today on the east coast of the US, you could use `{43511;43691}` for the dates, but not what you have. So having the dates in range of cells (not necessarily adjacent, but the same size as the Values range) is a way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `{ value, value }` construct
is called an *array constant*. 
As its name suggests, and as discussed (although not clearly)
in [Introducing array constants in Excel](https://web.archive.org/web/20140410081251/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/more-arrays-introducing-array-constants-in-excel-HA001087291.aspx),
the components of an array constant must be (scalar) ***constants***. 
So, for example, you can enter

```
={5, 12}
```

in a cell (or use `{5,12}` as part of a formula), but even

```
={5, 4+8}
```

is not valid. 
Obviously, `Today()` and `Today()+30*R[-1]C}` are not constants.

So, yes, unfortunately,
it looks like you have to put the *dates* array into cells. 
Of course, as is typically the case for “helper”-type cells,
they can be anywhere in the workbook<sup>1</sup>, and they can be hidden.

As long as you have room to type a long formula,
you might as well get it right. 
For some date *`D`*
(which might be `Today()`, a constant, a cell or a formula),

```
D+30*R3C2
```

is *`D`* plus 180 days (for `R3C2` = 6). 
You really should use

```
DATE(YEAR(D), MONTH(D)+R3C2, DAY(D))
```

to get *`D`* plus 6 months.
________________
<sup>1</sup> … as pointed out by Ron Rosenfeld [in a comment](https://superuser.com/q/1406338/150988#comment2121035_1406338).

Comment: DATE(YEAR(D),MONTH(D)+R3C2,DAY(D)) doesn't work for my purposes, since I'm more interested in an average month. One of my earlier formulas was actually XIRR(...{1;1+R3C2*(365.25/12)}), but I thought maybe the formula wasn't working because it wasn't recognizing those numbers as dates or because the second date was coming out to be a fraction, so that's when I switched to Today() and the nearest integer, 30. Also figured the above was just clearer for the purpose of the question, which was really about using the array. Thanks for the answer.